# 3TB HDD showing 512 logical sector size when connected via SATA

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, advanced-format

I have a [Seagate Expansion 3TB external hard drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178117) with data on it, and I wanted to get at [the drive inside the enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148844) and make it an internal drive. I'm using Windows 8, so the drive was being seen as having 4k sectors. When I connect via SATA, however, Windows reads the logical sector size as 512 bytes instead of 4096. In disk management it shows a protective GPT partition.
When I put the HDD back into the enclosure, it shows it as having 4K sectors, and it reads all my data.

Why is this happening, and how can I get the drive to work when it's connected via SATA?

Comment: This is likely handled by the controller card within the enclouser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was handled by the controller in the enclosure, so I had to format the drive before I could use it elsewhere.