# WD Blue 4TB not recognized

Tags: hard-drive

WD 4TB is USB connected to RPi2B. Appreciate your help.

```
# uname -r
4.14.69-v7+
```

HDparm displays 4000GB, however the kernel doesn't, probably therefor gdisk, fdisk don't either.

```
/var/log/syslog:
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19193.944765] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc_otg
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.076119] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.076140] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.076151] usb 1-1.5: Product: Ext HDD 1021
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.076164] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.076175] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 574343374B3553584B444650
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.077242] usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf kernel: [19194.085826] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
Sep 13 20:00:09 petaf mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.156098] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Ext HDD 1021     2002 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.157493] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.158559] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4294961152 512-byte logical blocks: **(2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)**
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.159885] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.160909] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.160926] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf kernel: [19195.189942] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Sep 13 20:00:10 petaf systemd-udevd[2880]: Process '/lib/udev/hdparm' failed with exit code 5.


# hdparm -I /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc: 

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD40EZRZ-00GXCB0
        Serial Number:      WD-WCC7K5SXKDFP
        Firmware Revision:  80.00A80
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x006d)
 ...
 ...
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  7814037168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     **3815447** MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     **4000787** MBytes (**4000** GB)

# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 2 TiB, 2199020109824 bytes, 4294961152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
cache/buffer size  = unknown
```

I'm experiencing this on both my RPi2B, and my Mint hosts. Both run a 4.+ generic kernel, and support 'GPT' and 'Advanced Partitions'.

```
# egrep '^[^#].*(EFI_PAR|TION_ADVANCED)' config
CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION=y
```

Comment: I had voted to close as duplicate of [Anyone know why older USB drive cases have a 2TB size limit?](https://superuser.com/q/622869/432690) Then I realized the answer there needs improvement and I retracted my vote. But this is probably it. Your USB-SATA adapter is the culprit.

Comment: It;s a USB2 case ... looked at differences between USB2 and 3 ... and lsusb-v output ... couldn't find anything ... that's not easy when you don't what you're looking for, and hadn't fully considered the adapter,  but would definitely, explain the issue on other hosts ... thanks very much.